# plan id not being assigned in Devise form. Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, rails-console

I have a `Rails` app with 3 sign up button links on the home page.
 Each has it's own plan assigned to it. Two of them go to a basic form while the third goes to a form with credit card details, handled by `Stripe`. The forms and Users are handled by `Devise`.

The plans seem to be setup correctly and are seen in the `rails console` however, when I go to `sign up`, to any of them, only the email address and password is captured, and NO `plan_id` is assigned.

I've noticed when previewing the form pages locally that the url at the top doesn't change to the specific form url, i.e `/users/sign_up?plan=3` for example, but instead shows the form but stays on the `homepage url?` I'm confused because the server seems to recognise which link i'm clicking on and which plan needs to be assigned?? Please Help!!

```
Started GET "/users/sign_up?plan=3" for 124.149.46.152 at 2015-08-21 06:32:19 +0000
Cannot render console from 124.149.46.152! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by Users::RegistrationsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"plan"=>"3"}
  Rendered devise/registrations/_paid.html.erb (8.1ms)
  Rendered devise/shared/_links.html.erb (0.3ms)
  Rendered devise/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application (11.6ms)
```

### Completed 200 OK in 154ms (Views: 151.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

console User.last

```
=> #<User id: 7, email: "testemail1@test.com", encrypted_password: "$2a$10$.EldkZ3KUdnz4u1dvIMkXO7U6GnAnrGNYomdITKqup....", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 1, current_sign_in_at: "2015-08-21 07:05:34", last_sign_in_at: "2015-08-21 07:05:34", current_sign_in_ip: "124.149.46.152", last_sign_in_ip: "124.149.46.152", created_at: "2015-08-21 07:05:34", updated_at: "2015-08-21 07:05:34", plan_id: nil, stripe_customer_token: nil>
```

and this is my application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected
    def configure_permitted_parameters
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:name, :stripe_card_token, :email, :password, :password_confirmation }
    end
end
```

---

development log

```
Started POST "/users" for 124.149.46.152 at 2015-08-21 07:31:57 +0000
Cannot render console from 124.149.46.152! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by Users::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"mA18/inejU2zEZiYXJq1xEtguLOEWnIV9UBozrHyXKPp2/2n9Ls7Km4+fCuZBL51EHUxSE+QJFRdbgW1fbMyew==", "user"=>{"email"=>"test10@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
  [1m[35m (0.4ms)[0m  begin transaction
  [1m[36mUser Exists (0.2ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'test10@gmail.com' LIMIT 1[0m
  [1m[35mSQL (0.6ms)[0m  INSERT INTO "users" ("email", "encrypted_password", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["email", "test10@gmail.com"], ["encrypted_password", "$2a$10$4cjIpysvXyckg0j4Kxzx9eqR9vVzqcmaQZPLdCC0X2jEik2MG/KrK"], ["created_at", "2015-08-21 07:31:57.381867"], ["updated_at", "2015-08-21 07:31:57.381867"]]
  [1m[36m (19.3ms)[0m  [1mcommit transaction[0m
  [1m[35m (0.2ms)[0m  begin transaction
  [1m[36mSQL (0.5ms)[0m  [1mUPDATE "users" SET "last_sign_in_at" = ?, "current_sign_in_at" = ?, "last_sign_in_ip" = ?, "current_sign_in_ip" = ?, "sign_in_count" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "users"."id" = ?[0m  [["last_sign_in_at", "2015-08-21 07:31:57.405089"], ["current_sign_in_at", "2015-08-21 07:31:57.405089"], ["last_sign_in_ip", "124.149.46.152"], ["current_sign_in_ip", "124.149.46.152"], ["sign_in_count", 1], ["updated_at", "2015-08-21 07:31:57.406791"], ["id", 8]]
  [1m[35m (19.7ms)[0m  commit transaction
Redirected to https://socialplayground-portal-runpixelrun.c9.io/
Completed 302 Found in 136ms (ActiveRecord: 40.9ms)


Started GET "/" for 124.149.46.152 at 2015-08-21 07:31:57 +0000
Cannot render console from 124.149.46.152! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
  [1m[36mPlan Load (0.4ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "plans".* FROM "plans" WHERE "plans"."id" = ? LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", 1]]
  [1m[35mPlan Load (0.2ms)[0m  SELECT  "plans".* FROM "plans" WHERE "plans"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
  [1m[36mPlan Load (0.2ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "plans".* FROM "plans" WHERE "plans"."id" = ? LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", 3]]
  Rendered pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (1.0ms)
  [1m[35mUser Load (0.4ms)[0m  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 8]]
Completed 200 OK in 210ms (Views: 207.3ms | ActiveRecord: 1.2ms)
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.7ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  ORDER BY "users"."id" DESC LIMIT 1[0m


Started DELETE "/users/sign_out" for 124.149.46.152 at 2015-08-21 07:35:08 +0000
Cannot render console from 124.149.46.152! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#destroy as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"p1LtsYqgP4SPYiiAh8/l1/XPNc888HMVob3thu5Y093WhGzoV8WJ41JNzDNCUe5mrtq8NPc6JVQJk4D9Ihm9BQ=="}
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.2ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", 8]]
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  begin transaction
  [1m[36m (0.1ms)[0m  [1mcommit transaction[0m
Redirected to https://socialplayground-portal-runpixelrun.c9.io/
Completed 302 Found in 10ms (ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)


Started GET "/" for 124.149.46.152 at 2015-08-21 07:35:08 +0000
Cannot render console from 124.149.46.152! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
  [1m[35mPlan Load (0.2ms)[0m  SELECT  "plans".* FROM "plans" WHERE "plans"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  [1m[36mPlan Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "plans".* FROM "plans" WHERE "plans"."id" = ? LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", 2]]
  [1m[35mPlan Load (0.1ms)[0m  SELECT  "plans".* FROM "plans" WHERE "plans"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 3]]
  Rendered pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (0.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 206ms (Views: 203.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)
```

---

/registrations_controller.rb

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  before_filter :select_plan, only: :new

  def create
    super do |resource|
      if params[:plan]
        resource.plan_id = params[:plan]
        if resource.plan_id == 3
          resource.save_with_payment
        else
          resource.save
        end
      end
    end
  end

  private  
  def select_plan
    unless params[:plan] && (params[:plan] == '1' || params[:plan] == '2' || params[:plan] == '3')
      flash[:notice] = "Please select a valid membership plan."
      redirect_to root_url
    end 
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

To allow plan_id to be save you need to add it in devise signup parameters. You can do this by adding following into your application controller

```
before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

def configure_permitted_parameters
   devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:email, :password_confirmation, :plan_id) }
end
```

Comment: Thanks @Ann10 for the reply :) ..but it's still not saving! I edited my question to include a screen grab of User.last

Comment: @RuNpiXelruN From your OP it seems like you are not adding plan_id to your permitted params

Comment: @usmanali Thanks for the reply! It is added sorry, after :password_confirmation, but still no luck!..any other ideas??

Comment: @RuNpiXelruN Can you paste what log is showing for this request?

Comment: @usmanali have attached the log now. Thanks for having a look, i'm completely stuck!

Comment: `"user"=>{"email"=>"test10@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}`

I don't see `plan_id` benig passed to this action

Comment: @usmanali below a little you can see plan_id ? among other things..sorry, so annoying!

Comment: @RuNpiXelruN Probably you didn't get me. What I wanted to say was that the parameters passed to the create action does not include `plan_id` while it should do so actually.

Comment: @usmanali Oh sorry, thanks. I've posted my registrations_controller.rb in the question above. I don't suppose you can say what's missing could you? Does params[:plan] need to be params[:plan_id] ? Thanks again, i really appreciate it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87570/discussion-between-usmanali-and-runpixelrun).

Comment: @usmanali I've taken this to chat. Thanks for helping out. I'll repost here if we find a solution!